# "No tests found. Nothing was run" message in console , unable to understand why

Tags: selenium, testng

Below is the code am trying to execute
    Not sure why am getting ***[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run***
    if I remove the before class annotation method, it executes but fails due the dependency

```
public class TestNG_Practice3 {

    static WebDriver driver ;
    String url = "https://in.linkedin.com/";            

    @BeforeClass(description = "To open the browser")
    public void openBrowser()
    {   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println("Browser got open");
    }

    @Test (dependsOnMethods ="openBrowser",description = "To signin")
    public void login()
    {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement signin = driver.findElement(By.id("login-email"));
        Assert.assertTrue(signin.isDisplayed());
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("login-password"));
        WebElement signinbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit"));
        signin.sendKeys("xyz");
        password.sendKeys("abc");
        signinbutton.click();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("feed/"));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "login")
    public void logout()
    {
        WebElement meDropdown =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-settings__dropdown-trigger\"]/div/span[2]/li-icon/svg"));
        meDropdown.click();
        WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("ember545"));
        logout.click();

    }       

    @AfterClass
    public void closebrowser()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1 : Basic trial with Project Build,**

```
public class TestNG_Demo {
 @BeforeClass
    public void openbrowser()
    {
        System.out.println("Browser got open");
    }

 @Test
    public void testbrowser()
    {
       System.out.println("Test execution");
    }

 @AfterClass
    public void closebrowser()
    {
        System.out.println("Browser got close");
    }
}
```

So you will be have idea, Your project build get successful execution.

If you have maven project and Build did not get pass, you will be have trigger what is causing from maven build dependency.

**Update**

**Step-2 : After tracing first trial**

```
public class TestNG_Demo {
    @Test
    public void testbrowser()
    {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.The basic project code you gave that's working.In my project am not using MAVEN for build.NOt sure why my original code is not working,it's not entering into the @beforeclass .

Comment: You should explore by single method. Don't go for BeforeClass and AfterClass annotation. Just Check by Test annotation. With couple of sentences or method. Check my updated answer for more reference.

Comment: It was jdk library issue.I had JDK 11 version which was giving issue, I change to JDK 8 and cleaned up the project and compiler reset.It worked.There was no issue with code.

Comment: It should not. Many people usign JDK 11 including me. This is one of the most common error if you have searched. It does not belongs with JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dependsOnMethods ="openBrowser"` because it's not a test method and will be execute before test without it